# VBA: Internet explorer control download

Tags: ms-access, internet-explorer, vba

Does anyone know of a way when using `InternetExplorer.Application` of using the [FileDownload Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb268220(v=vs.85).aspx) and what is possible with it? I'm trying to detect when IE is downloading a file so that when the file download is done the file is handled automatically.

There is a `DownloadBegin` and a `DownloadComplete` Events but this look to be talking about when navigating to a URL and not an accual file download.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to confirm the status of the download process.

```
Option Explicit
Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Sub DownloadFileAPI()
Dim strURL As String
Dim LocalFilePath As String
Dim DownloadStatus As Long

    strURL = "http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt"
    LocalFilePath = "C:\Test\TEST2_tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt"
    DownloadStatus = URLDownloadToFile(0, strURL, LocalFilePath, 0, 0)
    If DownloadStatus = 0 Then
        MsgBox "File Downloaded. Check in this path: " & LocalFilePath
    Else
        MsgBox "Download File Process Failed"
    End If
End Sub


Sub DownloadFile()
Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Dim oStream As Object
Dim myURL As String
Dim LocalFilePath As String

myURL = "http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt"
LocalFilePath = "C:\Test\TEST_tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt"

Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "", ""  '("username", "password")
WinHttpReq.send

If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile LocalFilePath, 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
    oStream.Close
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have to call a file download VIA Java script link (its displayed in the Dom as a incomplete link). How would I "bypass" the download dialog box?

Comment: Man, I have no idea!  I have never used Java a single day in my life.  However, I think it is somewhat like C#.  See the following link to see how to run a Macro using C#.  http://oakdome.com/programming/CSharp_RunExcelMacro.php

Comment: Thanks for the link. You should look into it. It's a great programming language.